# How to show that this subset is/is not a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I have this practice problem which is

> Consider the vector-space $U=F(-\infty,\infty)$,which is the vector-space of all functions from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, and the subset $V$ defined as:
>   $V:= \{\textbf{f} \in V \mid \textbf{f}(1)=0\}$
>   which is the set of functions which assigns the value of $0$ to $1$. Prove wether or not this subset is a subspace of $U$.

Thats part a) part be is the same but where $\textbf{f}(0)=1$. I am only asking for guidance for part a) which is what I quoted above...

My initial thought was to check the subspace criterion which is to check that it was closed under addition, and then check for scalar multiplication. I also had the thought of checking to make sure there is a zero vector.

But my problem that I am having is that I am trying to figure out how to check these conditions for a space for which is defined by functions instead of the typical vectors, but also how to account for the fact that $\textbf{f}(0)=1$ for all functions $\textbf{f} \in V$ also I should note that there is no specification on $\textbf{f}$ having to be continuous either.

If anyone could offer some guidance that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: It is to figure out if the subset V is a subspace of U.

Comment: Then say this in your question.

Comment: I made the edit, I thought I stated it but i never. My apologizes

Answer (score 2):

As you said one has to check the axioms, namely:

- Closure under addition
- Closure under scalar multiplication
- Neutral element

I will show the first as the rest is the same:

let $f,g$ in $V$. Then $f(1)=0=g(1)$.

Thus $$(f+g)(1)=f(1)+g(1)=0+0=0$$ and so $f+g$ satisfies the requirements to be in $V$, i.e. is in $V$. Consequently $V$ is closed under addition.

Answer (score 2):

### Part a) $V=\{f \in U \mid f(1)=0\}$

1. Closed under addition: let $f,g \in V$, i.e. $f(1)=g(1)=0$. Then, $(f+g)(1) = f(1)+g(1) = 0+0 = 0$. Thus, $f+g \in V$.
2. Closed under scalar multiplication: let $f \in V$ and $k \in F$ where $F$ is the field of scalars, i.e. $f(1)=0$. Then, $(kf)(1) = k(f(1)) = k(0) = 0$. Thus, $kf \in V$.
3. Contains $\mathbf{0}$: $\mathbf{0}(1) = 0$, so $\mathbf{0} \in V$.

Thus $V$ is a subspace of $U$.

### Part b) $V=\{f \in U \mid f(0)=1\}$

1. Closed under addition: let $f,g \in V$, i.e. $f(0)=g(0)=1$. Then, $(f+g)(0) = f(0)+g(0) = 1+1 = 2$. Thus, $f+g \notin V$.

Thus $V$ is not a subspace of $U$.

Comment: Strictly speaking, in (b) you would need to show $V$ is nonempty to get a counterexample.  (Or alternatively, just observe that the zero vector of $U$ is not in $V$.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler if $V$ is empty, then it isn't a subspace :)