# Proof of vector subspace on R functions

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F (\Bbb R,\Bbb R)$ be the vector space of all the functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$. For what values ​​of $k\in\Bbb R$, the set 
$W = \{f\in F (\Bbb R,\Bbb R)\mid f (1) = k\}\leqslant F$?

Any help?

Comment: What have you tried? What is the definition of a (linear) subspace?

Comment: Yeah, we need to proof the zero belongs to it, and the addition and scalar product also belongs. My doubt is what values of k accomplish that

Comment: [Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2426849/721644).

Comment: @cheesecake I think you change the question.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, the conditions for $W$ to be a linear subspace are that it should be closed under arbitrary linear combinations. That is for $f,g\in W$ and any $\alpha, \beta$

$$
\alpha f+ \beta g \in W
$$

In particular this should be true for $\alpha=\beta =0$ meaning that the null function should also be in $W$.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score -1):

If $W $ is a subspace, then the null-function belongs to  $W $

Can you proceed?

Comment: So 0: R->R and we can define it as 0(t) for any t in R.   0(1)=k??

Comment: @TonyStank $f(1)=0$ satisfies the condition $W\ne\emptyset$.

Comment: And $0(1)=k\iff k=0$.

Comment: thks, its similar to what I did, in the end the only value that satifies the subspace properties is if K=0